# Can't connect 2 bones correctly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

For some reason my bones is divided. I need to rotate almost whole body (with arms & head), but I can't do it because 1 bone is not connected to others.

Comment: you weight paint seems to be incorrect. Unfortunately we don't know, because you didn't show us that information so i recommend to provide your blend file so we don't have to guess.

Comment: @Chris oh yep, i have fixed the second issue, but there still the first issue with bones.. do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong about the bones? i can't connect them using "ctrl+j", they are like connected but in wrong way..

Comment: Please share your blend file so that we can check what's going on. See the [Guide to share your file](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> is for joining multiple objects into one. As far as I can see, your bones are all in the same armature (or at least your outliner shows an armature with 11 bones in it).

The issue here looks more like you expect a parent-child relationship between the bones, but your bones are independant from each other.

To parent a bone to another, go in Edit mode, select the child bone, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the parent, an hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> ► Make Parent. But you have two options from here; Keep Offset and Connected:

[image]

- **Keep Offset** is for child bones that you want to be detached from the parent. It also allows you to translate the child bone away from the parent. I.E. your upper arm and upper leg bones are not "connected" to any bone, you need them to be child of their parents with no connection.
- **Connected** is for child bones you want to always stay "stuck" with their parent with no possible offset between them. I.E. your spine bones, or the lower arms/legs. Any bone that needs to stay in a chain of bones and shouldn't be able to dislocate from each other.

In the future, when you create a rig and need a child bone, the simplest solution is to extrude a new bone by selecting the parent and pressing <kbd>E</kbd>. This will create a connected child bone, which you can then disconnect with <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> ► Disconnect while preserving the relationship.

Comment: Extruding helped in some way. But it did more harm than good. After I removed the old bone and pulled out the new one, the lower part of the character became invisible on Mixamo. I think it has something to do with Weight Paint too. (see 3rd image in my post). In blender it looks nice, but when i'm importing it to the Mixamo it looks like this..

Comment: You didn't need to extrude new bones, you could just redo your bones' parent relationships. If you make new bones, you have to either  redo the weights for these new bones, or rename your new bones as the old bones so that they can use the old bones' weights.

Comment: yes, i renamed the new bone, but i still have that invisible part, in blender it all looks good, but when i export it as .fbx and import on mixamo i have this problem.

Comment: want to clarify that exactly weight paint made mesh invisible, not a new bone.
but again, in blender my mesh looks nice, why it is so hard to archive this simple result...